# Proving Cauchy-Schwartz inequality without the vanish assumption of inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I've came accross the following question in a book that I'm studying from, about Hilbert spaces - 
[image]

And the answer is -

[image]

What  I don't understand is why 
[image]

implies that - [image]?

Comment: It is a quadratic polynomial in $\lambda$ that is non-negative for all values of $\lambda$. Therefore, its discriminant is not positive. Quadratic polynomials with positive discriminant take both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a quadratic of the form
$$P(\lambda)=C+\lambda B + A\lambda^2$$
and you know that $P(\lambda)\geq 0$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then
you must have $B^2-4AC\leq 0$, or else the quadratic would have two real roots, and consequently, will assume negative values. Now put $C=\langle x,x\rangle$,$A=\langle y,y\rangle$ and $B=2|\langle x,y\rangle|$, and you get
$$4|\langle x,y\rangle |^2\leq 4 \langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle$$
which gives the C-S inequality.